# Decimal format for another Decimal format on Android

Tags: android

I'm having trouble formatting this decimal value format (8487.0) for that format. "8.48".

I have tried the solution of other issues posted here but I did not succeed.

Example:

```
Double n1 = Double.parseDouble (String.valueOf (8487.0));
DecimalFormat dec = new DecimalFormat ("#. ##");
String credits = dec.format (n1);   Log.d (TAG, "test" + credits);
```

Currently it has the output like this: 8487

Any help is welcomed, Thanks.

Comment: What output are you expecting?

Comment: @Mandy8055  From 8487.0 to 8.48

Comment: `8487.0 = 8.487e3 `not `8.48`. So now please tell me exactly what do you want as output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use String format

```
String answer = String.format("%.2f", (8487.0 / 1000));        
Log.d(TAG, answer); //8.49
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two cases; whether you want to **round off** or not. Here's the sample code for both the cases.

```
double d = 8487.0;
d /= 1000;
DecimalFormat f = new DecimalFormat("##.00");
f.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.FLOOR);
String notRounded = f.format(d);
System.out.println("Not Rounded: " + notRounded);

f.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
String rounded = f.format(d);
System.out.println("Rounded: " + rounded);
```

Answer (score 0):

So, do you want to reduce the number by a factor 1000 ? e.g. g to kg ?

```
Double n1 = Double.parseDouble (String.valueOf (8487.0));
Double n2 = n1 / 1000;

DecimalFormat dec = new DecimalFormat ("#. ##");
String credits = dec.format(n2);

Log.d (TAG, "test" + credits);
```